# How to combine two templates in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XSLT templates that I need to combine into one and then sort it in alphabetic order:

```
<xsl:template match="properties-for-sale">
  <xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <option value="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="properties-for-rent">
  <xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <option value="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How can this be achieved in XSLT?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am just curious whether you need `<option value="{name}">` or `<option value="{name()}">` .. Anyways in my answer I have used `{name}` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `|` operator for matching

```
<xsl:template match="properties-for-sale|properties-for-rent">
  <xsl:for-each select="entry">
    <option value="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Oh excellent. That works. Thanks a lot! Just wondering how I can reference that template from another stylesheet? Since it doesn't have a name, that is a bit tricky, no? Sorry, XML n00b...

Comment: @Tintin81 You don't have to reference templates at all. The XSLT processor does that for you. Also, you really should not use `<xsl:for-each>`. Instead, you should write an `<xsl:template match="entry">` that outputs `<option>` elements and use `<xsl:apply-templates select="entry" />`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="properties-for-sale|properties-for-rent">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry">
      <xsl:sort select="name" order="ascending"/>
      <option value="{name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

use `|` for multiple XPaths.. and use `<xsl:sort>` for sorting the values ..

a reference if you want to know more about it!

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp